# How do I escape this $row in the anchor tag?

Tags: php

This is just a simple question of mine and I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
echo '<li><a href="profile.php?username=$row['username']> Profile</a></li>';
```

Comment: Single quoted strings don't support variables in them. You must either concatenate or change them to double quotes.

Comment: How would that look? @Isac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used single quotes to escape the variable. Also you forgot to add a `"` at the end of the href attribute.

```
echo '<li><a href="profile.php?username='.$row['username'].'"> Profile</a></li>';
```

Comment: Thank you! @KevinP

Answer (score 1):

Single quoted strings don't support variables in them. So you can either concatenate the the parts of the string that you want, using the appropriate operator for that, the `.`

```
echo '<li><a href="profile.php?username=' . $row['username'] . '"> Profile</a></li>';
```

Or change the single quotes to double quotes, which turns the html double quotes into escaped ones:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"profile.php?username=${row['username']}\"> Profile</a></li>";
```

Note how the `href` starting and ending quote changed to `\"`, not to end the starting `echo` double quote.

The `$row['username']` also had to be changed to `${row['username']}` because it is an array access with a string key. If it was a normal variable like `$x` or an integer key like `$row[0]` it wouldn't need the `{` `}` around it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define before a string?

I.E:

```
$usr=$row["username"];
echo "<li><a href='profile.php?username=$usr'> Profile</a></li>";
```

When you define a string you can use it inside an echo with doublequotes